# Return cv::Rect and cv::RotatedRect from C++ code using JNI

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm writing a C++ dll which will be used from a Java code. Some of my methods have a return value with OpenCV object type such as `cv::Mat`, `cv::Rect`, `cv::RotatedRect`. I can return `cv::Mat` by the following code. But I don't know how to return `cv::Rect` or `cv::RotatedRect`, so to say custom object type.

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_tr_com_imageprocessing_ImageProvider_grabImage0(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    if(mat != nullptr) // this is satisfied if memory is already allocated and not deleted
    {
        delete mat;
        mat = nullptr;
    }
    mat = new cv::Mat(imageProvider.grabImage());
    return (jlong)mat;
}
```

In the code above `mat` and `imageProvider` are declared as global variables.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Does the code below ok?

*Again* `rect` *and* `shapeProvider` *are declared as global variables.*

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_tr_com_provus_impro_ShapeProvider_rect0(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    if(rect != nullptr) // this is satisfied if memory is already allocated and not deleted
    {
        delete rect;
        rect = nullptr;
    }
    rect = new cv::Rect(shapeProvider.rect());
    return (jlong)rect;
}
```

Comment: You can't specify the C++ type on a return.  You will only be able to return a pointer to the C++ object.  Its up to you, in your java layer to store the pointer, as a long, and pass it back to the C++ code where appropriate.  If you are unsure of the type returned( as in the native function can return multiple data types ), you will need to use a `dynamic_cast<T>(ptr)` when the ptr is accessed in the c++ layer.

Comment: @Samhain can you verify the edited version of the question? Thank you.

Comment: that looks fine.  Every c++ object's address is going to be represented in java as a long.  You will need to manage its "type" in Java by just remembering what you created(as in which JNI function did you call to create it).  Likewise, when you pass it back to the JNI functions for use later, you will need to cast it appropriately.